# ElasticSearch Read element on array

Tags: arrays, indexing, elasticsearch

I'm working with Elasticsearch, currently I have a struct like that

```
{
    "took": 2,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "999999",
                "_type": "content",
                "_id": "NmYTku",
                "_score": 1,
                "_source": {
                    "internal_id": "NmYTk4",
                    "external_id": "Ga_UI502",
                    "
                    "images": [
                        {
                            "uri_id": "2939306",
                            "url": "14mast_head.jpg",
                            "type": "Masthead",
                            "orientation": "Landscape",
                            "x_resolution": 3280,
                            "y_resolution": 1480
                        },
                        {
                            "uri_id": "Galavision/POST_poster/2939306",
                            "url": "140603_29un_erro_poster.jpg",
                            "type": "Poster",
                            "orientation": "Portrait",
                            "x_resolution": 720,
                            "y_resolution": 405
                        },
                        {
                            "uri_id": "Galavision/POST_poster_title/2939306",
                            "url": "140603_29un_erro_poster_title.jpg",
                            "type": "PosterWithTitle",
                            "orientation": "Portrait",
                            "x_resolution": 924,
                            "y_resolution": 518
                        },
                        {
                            "uri_id": "Galavision/POST_poster_cover/2939306",
                            "url": "140603_29poster_cover.jpg",
                            "type": "Poster",
                            "orientation": "Landscape",
                            "x_resolution": 600,
                            "y_resolution": 868
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I was wondering, how can I get only one value from my array e.g.
I want to have only the images with oritentation on Landscape and type Poster. I tried with This query but it only returns me  all the image elements.

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": { "term":{"_id":"NmYTku"} }
    }
},
  "_source": ["images"]
}
```

I don't have idea how do a filter on the elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using nested or child fields for the images? If not, that doc is actually being indexed like:

```
...
images.uri_id = [1, 2, 3, 4, etc..]
images.url = [1, 2, 3, 4, etc..]
images.type = [1, 2, 3, 4, etc..]
...
```

so the distinction between individual elements is gone. Try giving this a read:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/complex-core-fields.html

If you don't need to query, why not just filter out the ones you like client side?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
  "filtered": {
    "query": {
      "match": { "term": "_id" : "NmYTku" }
},
  "_source": [images]{
    "orientation": "landscape",
    "type": "Poster",
  }
}
```